# Program in c crashes

Tags: c

My code seems to crash everytime i run it, i want to make a program that finds a capital letter in a sentence (str[max]) and it prints out how many times it finds it

i get a warning from the build log (warning: 'c' may be used uninitialized in this function)  (very entry level programmer here !!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "ctype.h"


#define max 26

void checktimes(char str[],char temp);

int main()
{
char str[max], temp;
printf("Type a sentence with 25 characters max :");
gets(str);

int i;
for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
{
temp = str[i];
 if(isupper(temp))
    checktimes(str,temp);
}
 return 0;
}

void checktimes(char str[],char temp)
{
int j,i;
char c;
for(j=0; j<=max ; j++)
{
    str[i] = c;
    if(c == temp)
        i++;
}
printf("%c --> %d",temp,i);
```

}

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=max;i++)` - `i` will go from `0` to `max` *inclusive*. See a problem? Well, and the standard no-no about `gets`..

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: The error message is very specific about your problem.  Also, learn to use a debugger (give a man a fish, .......)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems:

1) Never use `gets()`. Use `fgets()` instead.

2) You may not always have `max` number of characters. So, your condition: `for(i=0;i<=max;i++)` is probably wrong.
   Use `strlen()` to find out the actual number of chars in `str`.

3) You are reading `c` uninitialized here:

```
str[i] = c;
```

You probably meant:

```
c = str[j]; /* notice the i -> j change */
```

4) The argument to `isupper()` requires a cast to `unsigned char`.

5) Initialize `i` to `0` in `checktimes()`.

---

In fact, there's a logical error as well. You would be printing the count of duplicate chars as many times.
If you use an temp array, it can be written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define max 26

void checktimes(char str[]);

int main(void)
{
    char str[max];
    printf("Type a sentence with 25 characters max :");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0; /* To remove the trailing newline if any. */
    checktimes(str);
    return 0;
}

void checktimes(char str[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int count[max] = {0};
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(isupper((unsigned char)str[i]))
            count[str[i] - 'A']++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    if (count[i])
        printf("%c --> %d\n",i+'A', count[i]);
}
```

Comment: If `isupper` is defined as `int isupper( int ch );`, why does the argument have to be cast to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @RandomDavis toupper takes an `int` value which must be representable in an `unsigned char`. So, the cast helps avoid potential undefined behaviour.
For example, `toupper(-5);` is UB. It's all detailed in `man toupper`. The same applies to other functions in ctype.h.